# react-apollo perfomance issue on android

Tags: android, performance, react-native, react-apollo, react-native-flatlist

For me, it seems that  in react-apollo has some performance issues on Android
For example, I have a FlatList of elements, each of which has

```
<Query
        query={cardUniversalQuery}
        variables={{
          date: date.format(innerDateFormat)
        }}
        delay>
        {({ data }) => (
          <FlatList
            data={data && data.userDayActivities ? data.userDayActivities : []}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem {...item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => ((index).toString())} />)}
      </Query>
```

if remove Query - android and ios version works with roundly the same speed, while go through a list.

But if return that section back - it blocks JS thread until all queries in {windowSize} items are finished - so that UI is still response on scroll but their proper handlers can’t be fired.
Ios work fine - just show empty space in place of query, and don't block JS/UI thread (perf monitor shows just reducing fps to the range of 30-50 on ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of caching is coming. It helps a LOT! And make android version works as fast as IOS
link of upcoming PR: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/3394